# Blocking tor traffic with postfix or fail2ban on mailserver

Tags: ubuntu, postfix, dovecot, fail2ban, tor

I am running an Ubuntu 20.04 Lemp server, with postfix/dovecot. I have fail2ban set up so that if 2 unsuccessful loging attempts to my email are made by the same ip address, fail2ban bans the ip's from accessing anything on my server. However, In my postfix logs, I have noticed tor traffic trying to access my email server. The problem with this is that since tor ip's are constantly changing, fail2ban fails to detect the same IP guessing passwords, even though it is most likely the same user using tor to make connection attempts. I am wondering if there is a way to block tor traffic with fail2ban, or block it completely from my LEMP server, so that no tor traffic can make connection attempts to my email server.

Answer (score 2):

Normally you use fail2ban to generate an IP blocklist based on abuse patterns found in your own log files.

Your use case is different and I wouldn't use fail2ban for that.

The TOR network provides a ready made list of current TOR exit nodes here https://check.torproject.org/torbulkexitlist

Simply download and refresh that list regularly and use that as input for a separate IP blocklist, as separate iptables rules.

```
 wget https://check.torproject.org/torbulkexitlist
```

The most efficient way to make and maintain an iptables rule with such a list of unique IP's is with `ipset`.

```
 ipset create blacklist-tor     hash:ip hashsize 65536

 ipset create blacklist-tor-tmp hash:ip hashsize 65536
```

Use a temporary ipset when adding IP's

```
 ipset flush  blacklist-tor-tmp

 for TOR_IP in $(cat torbulkexitlist) ;  do ipset add blacklist-tor-tmp $TOR_IP) ; done
```

Atomically activate the list with latest IP's with the `ipset swap` funtion: :

```
 ipset swap blacklist-tor-tmp blacklist-tor
```

And then create/add a single rule that checks the ipset for TOR exit nodes and categorically block those:

```
 iptables -I INPUT_direct -p tcp -m multiport --dports 25,587,110,995,143,993 -m set --match-set blacklist-tor  src -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
```

Comment: "And then create/add a single rule that checks the ipset for TOR exit nodes and categorically block those:" I am using UFW, not iptables. Is there a way to do this with UFW? Or can I use UFW and iptables at the same time?

Comment: UFW is a front-end to iptables. I don't think the UFW framework has native support for ipset based rules, but UFW supports adding  raw rules to  add non-standard rules such as the one using ipset lists.

Comment: Thank you, but I am still a bit confused. Would UFW Raw rules be that of those rules added to /etc/ufw/before.rules? such as .... -I INPUT_direct -p tcp -m multiport --dports 25,587,110,995,143,993 -m set --match-set blacklist-tor  src -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable ?

Comment: ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ @HBruijn

Comment: I just revisited this answer and noticed your comment and I have to admit, I don't know the intricacies of ufw and don't have a recommendation on how/where to add this.