# fail2ban include list of ip addresses to ban

Tags: fail2ban, blacklist

Suppose I have a .txt file containing a list of ip addresses I'd like to ban for some amount of time (so, a blacklist file of some sort). I know how do do this in Apache (for example) - simply by including the .txt file into apache.conf and then doing a graceful restart.

I was wondering if the same thing was possible using fail2ban, wherein I somehow get fail2ban to periodically 'read in' the list of ip addresses I'd like to ban, making use of the fail2ban machinery to communicate with iptables?

Comment: `fail2ban-client ban <ip>` will mostly do the job. you can read the [manual online](https://linux.die.net/man/1/fail2ban-client)

Comment: OK -- I'll check that out.  Banning a single IP seems easy. But, a list of hundreds -> thousands? The .txt file is actually a list of tor exit nodes I want to block. Said file is updated every 6 hours. So, every 6 hours I need to unban the previous list, and ban the new list (although some node ips won't change).

Comment: You wouldn’t really use fail2ban for that. Create a firewall rule that references an `ipset` as the source and/or destination. You can load an updates list ip-addresses or ranges and then `ipset swap` an existing ipset with a new one as an atomic transaction. https://ipset.netfilter.org/

Comment: The [answer below](https://serverfault.com/a/1151986/37681) explains much better why you shouldn't use fail2ban, as to how to implement a solution with ipset: see this Q&A here for an approach : https://serverfault.com/a/1106655/37681  where you create the firewall rule(s) once and then periodically update the ipset

Comment: "Said file is updated every 6 hours" - maybe you should wire the origin of this data directly into your local logs so fail2ban can do its thing instead of inventing complexity.

Comment: Several good suggestions. Thanks. Putting the exit node list into the logs is easy, so I'll try that first. But...I'll also have a look at ipset.

Answer (score 1):

Fail2ban is for managing a list of addresses to ban *automatically*.

Everything rests on an assumption that if there are several consecutive "errors" from the *same* remote address, these "errors" aren't accidental and the address is malicious and is trying to do something nasty (e.g. brute-force passwords, scan for vulnerabilities, etc). Errors is taken into quotes because it's up to a definition — what to consider "an error" is defined by *filters* in fail2ban. It expects that an application *logs* something *in real time* (almost) when it discovers a problem in a communication, and also that log message contains an address of the remote that it was communicating with.

Such kind of detection is not error-free itself. The legitimate user might misremember their password and try several near guesses when logging in; how these attempts appear in logs doesn't differ from genuine brute force. If they were too insisting and rushy it will they will get banned, and that is an actual false positive.

Remote IPs also often are just infected computers, and after some time they will appear under another IP; the previous IP they were occupying can be taken by some other, innocent actor, and that system will find itself banned incorrectly. Infected and vulnerable systems also sometimes being cured and fixed, so they are no longer dangerous.

To account for all of this, bans that are imposed by fail2ban are *not permanent*, and it will automatically remove the ban after some time.

It's all different when you have an *a priori* list of addresses to ban. First of all, typically these addresses are not addresses, but *network blocks* (a sets of adjacent addresses). Second, entries of that list are *known to not expire*; we assume that entitis that operate these network blocks *are malicious*. And, finally, the most important: **fail2ban is awful at managing large ban lists**. It is only good and usable because it's automatic; **don't try to use it with thousands of addresses**. Just starting/stopping it with the thousand of addresses in a database will result in substantial processing time (tens of minutes).

Use your firewall directly for cases when you have a list of addresses. Don't attempt to manage it with fail2ban. Rather, if you discover some addresses (or close sets of addresses, like small subnets) that get automatically banned and unbanned often, it can be advantageous to investigate on these and, probably, ban them by hand for fail2ban to never deal with them again.

Comment: "an assumption that if there are several consecutive 'errors'" - no, that is how the default config for ssh works. It doesn't have to be the case. "might misremember their password and try several near guesses when logging in" - again true for default ssh config. Not necessarily the case otherwise. "when you have an a priori list of addresses" - subsequent update in comments states this changes every 6 hours implying not *a priori*.